# ImportError: cannot import name 'SentencePieceModel' from 'sentencepiece' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sentencepiece/__init__.py)

Tags: google-colaboratory, sentencepiece

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

in <cell line: 4>()
2 import numpy as np
3 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
----> 4 from sentencepiece import SentencePieceModel
5 from transformers import XLNetTokenizer, XLNetModel
6 from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16

ImportError: cannot import name 'SentencePieceModel' from 'sentencepiece' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sentencepiece/**init**.py)

Uninstalling, reinstalling then restarting the runtime.